# AttributeErrror at sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I just installed sklearn using pip. When I try to import anything I get an AttributeError.

```
import sklearn # No error

from sklearn import svm # AttributeError

from sklearn import datasets # Same AttributeError
```

> Full output:     Traceback (most recent call last):       test.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from sklearn import cluster       File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster__init__.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering   File
>   "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py",
>   line 15, in 
>       from ..metrics.pairwise import pairwise_kernels   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics__init__.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from .ranking import auc   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from scipy.stats import rankdata   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats__init__.py",
>   line 345, in 
>       from .stats import *   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py",
>   line 171, in 
>       from . import distributions   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py",
>   line 13, in 
>       from . import _continuous_distns   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_continuous_distns.py",
>   line 113, in 
>       class norm_gen(rv_continuous):   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_continuous_distns.py",
>   line 175, in norm_gen
>       `optimizer` argument is ignored.\n\n""")   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\doccer.py",
>   line 159, in _doc
>       start_of_notes = cls_docstring.find(notes_header) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

```
# From doccer.py
def _doc(func):
    cls_docstring = getattr(cls, func.__name__).__doc__
    notes_header = '        Notes\n        -----\n'
    # XXX The following assumes that there is a Notes section.
    start_of_notes = cls_docstring.find(notes_header) # This is line 159
    end_of_notes = cls_docstring.find('        References\n')
    if end_of_notes == -1:
        end_of_notes = cls_docstring.find('        Examples\n')
        if end_of_notes == -1:
            end_of_notes = len(cls_docstring)
    func.__doc__ = (cls_docstring[:start_of_notes + len(notes_header)] +
                    notes +
                    cls_docstring[end_of_notes:])
    return func
return _doc
```

I'm using Python 3.7.1

Does anyone have an idea how this problem can be fixed?
I'm not sure what more information to include, so if you need more information please tell me to do so.

EDIT1:
I tried doing the exact same thing on my pc, and it works just fine. This problem only occurs when using my laptop.

Comment: Are you running Python with `-OO` on? If so, try turning off `-OO`.

Comment: It would help to post the complete, exact error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what -oo is, and how do I turn it off?

Comment: `-OO` is a [command-line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-oo). Depending on how you're running Python, you may need to check IDE options or something similar to see what the command line options look like.

Comment: Type `import sklearn` and the `sklearn.__version__`. What is the output ?

Comment: output will be 0.20.0

Comment: Ok. Try what I suggested in my answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a broken installation probelm.

Try these please:

Open your terminal (cmd) and try these before you try to import the sklearn.

```
pip3 install -U scikit-learn
```

Also make sure your have numpy and scipy:

```
pip3 install numpy 
pip3 install scipy
```

---

Edit 1:

Try also this:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn
sudo pip install scikit-learn
```

Comment: I tried doing this. scikit-learn command gave me 'requirement already up-to-date', while the two other commands gave me 'requirements already satisfied'
I then tried printing sklearn.__version__, and it gave me 0.20.0, and from sklearn import datasets gave me same error.

Comment: Windows or MacOS? Also, try `pip uninstall scikit-learn` and then `sudo pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: I cannot uninstall scikit-learn either, it gives 'FileNotFoundError'. I suspect that it's because I have a whitespace in my c-drive username. I'll try to figure out how to rename it and see if it makes any change

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: I believe that the package is installed in the wrong location. You need to uninstall it and then install it again. Do you use `conda` ??

Answer (score 0):

My current user has a whitespace in the c-drive user name. I tried making another user on my laptop without that whitespace, downloaded python 3.7.1 and pip installed scikit-learn and it worked just fine!